Can Google Scholar capture citations without arXiv DOI
I had a paper uploaded to arXiv. Today I noticed there are two new papers citing my paper with the correct title and author names but both without my arXiv DOI. This is because they use @misc format exported from arXiv when citing it in .bib, so arXiv DOI won't be shown in compiled PDF. Currently, Google Scholar has not counted them towards my citation. I wonder whether Google Scholar can capture these citations in the end?
By the way, I have checked that other papers cited by them has correctly gained the citations. Also, Semantic Scholar is able to get correct citation count.

Google Scholar is not necessarily the best way to know someones citations exactly. Its not rare for it to not count, or even double count references (when the article is put in two different repositories with different formats). Don't worry too much about what Google Scholar says, its just approximate.
